# Merge Dict Key Value

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have two files both with key and value. I am trying to merge them with corresponding `key` and `value`. Keys are present in both the files and `value1` in `file1` and `value2` in `file2`. The files have many columns and `key` in both files are in `col[0] col[1]`

I am trying to get something like this:

```
key  value1 value2
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d2 = {}

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for row in file2:
        cols = row.strip().split()
        #print(cols);
        key = cols[0], cols[1]
        value1 = cols[4]
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
        cols = row.strip().split()
        #print(cols);
        key = cols[0], cols[1]
        value2 = cols[2]

        print ("%s %s %s %s\n" % (d2[cols[0]], d2[cols[1]], d2[cols[4]], d2[cols[2]]))

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_two.py", line 21, in <module>
    print ("%s %s %s %s\n" % (d2[cols[0]], d2[cols[1]], d2[cols[4]], d2[cols[2]]))
KeyError: '3545' (first line)
```

Comment: It should be `d.items()`.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 so i used `d.iteritems()` and that gives an error.

Comment: Ouch! It should be `for row in d`. But since your file contains only 3 columns you're going to get `IndexError` on `value2 = cols[4]`.

Comment: I am having one file with 3 cols and other file with 5 cols

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did also change the code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for d in (file1,file2):
```

Here, `f` is one of your files.

```
    for key, value in d:
```

If you iterate over the file, you get *lines* (strings). When you iterate over a line (string), you get *characters*. So, unless all lines in your files are two characters long, `for key, value in d` will fail.

The rest of your code (`cols = row.strip().split()` ) seems right, although, it's not clear where `row` comes from. As  Ashwini Chaudhary said, you probably wanted `for row in d`

Comment: I changed the code. In the previous code it was not clear `col[4]` to be taken from which file.